# Mockito seams to be incompatible with Spring Cache

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I am getting unexpected behaviors when trying to use Mockito with Spring Cache.

It seams that Mockito do not work well with the Spring AOP. Could anyone confirme to me that it is a bug or if I am doing something wrong?

In this code, we can see that the test will throws an `SpelEvaluationException` when trying to stub the method.

You can reproduce the problem cloning this GitHub repository. There you will find the pom.xml with all dependencies.

https://github.com/brunogcarneiro/spring-cache-mockito-incompatibility

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class SpringCacheMockitoIncompatibilityTest {

    interface MyRepo extends Repository<Object, Long> {

        //@Cacheable(cacheNames = "sample", key="#key.id")
        @Cacheable(cacheNames = "sample", key = "new org.springframework.cache.interceptor.SimpleKey(#key.id)")
        Object findByEmail(MyKey key);
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class MyKey{
        long id;
        String name;

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj){
            return id == ((MyKey)obj).id;
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableCaching
    static class Config {

        @Bean
        CacheManager cacheManager() {
            return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("sample");
        }

        @Bean
        MyRepo myRepo() {
            return Mockito.mock(MyRepo.class);
        }
    }

    @Autowired CacheManager manager;
    @Autowired MyRepo repo;

    @Test
    public void throwsSpelEvaluationException_whenAnyMatcherIsUsedWithObject() {

        Object first = new Object();

        MyKey myKey = new MyKey(1l,"name");

        //both lines below will throws SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'id' cannot be found on null

        //doReturn(first).when(repo).findByEmail(any(MyKey.class));
        doReturn(first).when(repo).findByEmail(myKey);

        Object result1 = repo.findByEmail(myKey);

        verify(repo,times(1)).findByEmail(myKey);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you might have over simplified your example. You are just asserting on a mock, which is pointless. I get minimal reproducible example, but I can't figure out what the end goal is here. Why add the `@Cacheble` to a mock? Why test `@Cacheable`? Spring has already done that. Just not sure what the desired result is and why.

Comment: Hy @DCTID, thank you! **Why test `@Cacheable`?** I do not want to test `@Cacheable`, I want to test if my implementation using Spring Cache is working. My implementation is far more complex than this minimal reproducible example. But I think that this example is absolutely clear showing some unexpected behavior when using Mockito with Spring Cache.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this, but I am getting a different exception when the mock behaviour is defined. It looks like the `AOP`-impl of the `@Cachable` interferes at this point and causes the whole thing to fail. Mabye you can add the dependencies you are using. But I am not sure why you want to involve mockito into this test?

Comment: Hi @second! Thank you! I am getting no exception. The problem is that the variable `result` is receiving null instead of the same reference of the variable `first`. 

All the dependencies can be found at this [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/brunogcarneiro/1a65b8f8a6147315042bbc319f709690).

I will update the code to explain what I want to test. See there...

Comment: @second it is important to understand that this is a **minimal reproducible example**. The actual behavior is far more complex than this. It should test a combination of @ Cacheable @ CacheEvict and @ CachePut.

Comment: I can confirm, that I also had problems with Spring AOP in combination with Mockito Mocks. So there seams to be a general problem with that combination.

Comment: @BrunoCarneiro: If I am not mistaken your link only contains that one file, nothing like a pom.xml which would tell me which specific version you are using.

Comment: Well, keep in mind: AOP is a framework that rewrites byte code. Mockito is a framework that generates bytecode dynamically. Be glad when it works in the first place ...

Comment: @second I have created a GitHub repository to share the full code with pom.xml. It was very strange because in the new repo the behavior was different but still not correct. Even though I have used the same version of the dependencies. Please, see the updated question to find the link to the repo.

Comment: Now you have the same error message that I had when I tried to run your test.